# SSL certificate pinning with libcurl

Tags: ssl, curl, ssl-certificate, pinning

I'd like to know if this example is enough to provide certificate pinning with libcurl:
http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/cacertinmem.html

because I have found that curl also allows http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.html

Since I'll be using a self-signed certificate and only trust on it I don't know if it's truly necessary to pinn it too.

resume: Can the connection be compromised if I only add my certificate (self-signed) to the x509 certificate store like the example? do I need to add extra checks? do I need to use the CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY option?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find another example in the implementation of the new curl option in git 2.8 (March 2016):

See [commit aeff8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeff8a61216bf6e0d663c08c583bc8552fa3c344) (15 Feb 2016) by [Christoph Egger (`siccegge`)](https://github.com/siccegge).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e79112d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e79112d21024beb997951381db21a70b087d459d), 24 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `http`: implement public key pinning
>
> Add the `http.pinnedpubkey` configuration option for public key pinning. It allows any string supported by `libcurl` -- `base64(sha256(pubkey))` or `filename` of the full public key.
>
> If cURL does not support pinning (is too old) output a warning to the user.

The [`git config` man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aeff8a61216bf6e0d663c08c583bc8552fa3c344/Documentation/config.txt#L1682-L1688) mentions:

```
http.pinnedpubkey:
```

> Public key of the https service.
> It may either be the filename of a PEM or DER encoded public key file or a string starting with '`sha256//`' followed by the base64 encoded sha256 hash of the public key.
> See also [libcurl 'CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY'](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_PINNEDPUBLICKEY.html).
> git will exit with an error if this option is set but not supported by cURL.

---

With Git 2.34 (Q4 2021), HTTPS error handling is updated when it comes to SSL certificate pinning:

See [commit 3e8084f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e8084f1884ffea25b80f76b7a1bd0e5b3200c8a) (24 Sep 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 97492aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/97492aacffee48dd217164f6af4b9d1db1aa6646), 11 Oct 2021)</sup>

> ### [`http`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3e8084f1884ffea25b80f76b7a1bd0e5b3200c8a): check `CURLE_SSL_PINNEDPUBKEYNOTMATCH` when emitting errors
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> Change the error shown when a `http.pinnedPubKey` doesn't match to point the `http.pinnedPubKey` variable added in [aeff8a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeff8a61216bf6e0d663c08c583bc8552fa3c344) ("`http`: implement public key pinning", 2016-02-15, Git v2.8.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e79112d21024beb997951381db21a70b087d459d) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/56f37fda511e1615dc6df86c68f3b841711a7828)), e.g.:
>
> ```
> git -c http.pinnedPubKey=sha256/someNonMatchingKey ls-remote https://github.com/git/git.git
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/git.git/' with http.pinnedPubkey configuration: SSL: public key does not match pinned public key!
> ```
>
> Before this we'd emit the exact same thing without the " `with http.pinnedPubkey configuration`".
> The advantage of doing this is that we're going to get a translated message (everything after the "`:`" is hardcoded in English in `libcurl`), and we've got a reference to the `git-specific` configuration variable that is causing the error.
>
> Unfortunately we can't test this easily, as there are no tests that require `https://` in the test suite, and `t/lib-httpd.sh` doesn't know how to set up such tests.
> See [this thread](https://lore.kernel.org/git/YUonS1uoZlZEt+Yd@coredump.intra.peff.net/) for the start of a discussion about what it would take to have divergent "`t/lib-httpd/apache.conf`" test setups.