# Validating an SSL certificate's organisation name in CURL

Tags: ssl, curl

I am using cURL to download update files to a device from one of my servers. The update is triggered by a HTTP request to the device which contains the URL to download the update from. Given this URL could be anything to secure this I would like to validate the server in the URL as my own before initiating the download. There are also a number of caveats to the server in question:

- The common name of the server may change in the future so the solution has to be able to adapt to this. Once the script is live access to the device will be limited, so changing configurations (like the expected common name) should be avoided.
- The server is secured under HTTPS and has a trusted root CA signed SSL certificate. I would like to keep using a trusted SSL certificate over a self signed one.

### Considered solutions

- Using a self-signed CA on the server and ensuring the server's certificate is signed by this CA before initiating the download. However, this has the disadvantage of the certificate not being trusted by browsers etc.
- One idea is to inspect the "organisation name" on the server's certificate and ensure it matches my organisation. This would allow me to keep using the trusted certificate and wouldn't change if the common name changes. **Is there any way to do this using CURL?**

**Failing this are there any other tools / solutions which could be used to achieve this?**

### Thoughts

- To achieve this I may need to hook into the SSL validation which I assume is conducted by an external tool like openssl?
- CURL already checks the "common name" in the certificate and checks it against the requested domain name, maybe I can hook into this?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with this which is not already achieved with the existing check of the common name. If you fear that somebody can create a certificate with the same common name then the same could include your organisation name in the certificate too.

Comment: I should have added that the common name of the server is subject to change so I am looking to validate an additional field which is not going to change. Additionally, the existing check of the common name only checks it matches the requested domain name not a name I specify.

Comment: *"...the existing check of the common name only checks it matches the requested domain name not a name I specify..."* - I still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Don't you specify the URL and thus what is expected in the certificate CN/SAN? And if the goal is to accept any URL as long the certificate is issued by you then it would be better to use your own CA and accept only certificates issued by this CA. Maybe you could describe the broader problem you are trying to solve instead of your particular solution idea (i.e. [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/)).

Comment: Agreed my question is definitely falling into the XY problem, in hindsight I should have asked it more broadly. I will edit it and add why I have settled on this solution.

Comment: If the common name/SAN of the certificate changes your code to access the site would need to change anyway you would need to change the URL to access since otherwise the validation will fail. Thus I still don't get why you need additional validation apart from the name. If you want to make really sure instead that this is actually your certificate have a look at key pinning:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955337/ssl-certificate-pinning-with-libcurl.

Comment: With regards to the initial validation I only want to make sure the server has a trusted root CA signed certificate. This isn't be dependent on the request URL so shouldn't break if the common name of the server changes (given that the server's certificate is valid for that CN). As an extension to ensure the server is mine, and not one of the many servers with trusted root CA signed certificates, I am suggesting extracting something from the server certificate which uniquely identifies my server and that won't change with new different certificates.

Comment: *"... I am suggesting extracting something from the server certificate which uniquely identifies my server and that won't change with new different certificates. .."* - commonly the public key is used for this. You can reuse the same key if the certificate changes. And its the only thing where you can really be sure that nobody has faked it.

Comment: This must be what you refer to in key pinning. Now I just need a way to validate this in cURL and it looks like "--pinnedpubkey" will do the job. Thanks!